# autenticação com FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp

Preciso fazer a persistência de inclusoes, alterações e exclusões que os usuários fazem no sistema, cada movimentação que o usuário faz só ele vê, então criei um `Id` nas tabelas do meu *BD* para saber qual usuário que está gravando os dados.

Eu estava usando a *Session*, quando o usuário logava eu atribuia a session com o `Id` do usuário no *BD*, isso causou vários problemas porque o *IIS* faz *recycle* do *pool* e limpa os dados da *sessions*.

Então resolvi usar o `FormsAuthenticationTicket` já que consigo usar o *role* no `user_data`, e o *login*, porém não consigo atribuir o `ID` do usuário, então criei um *Select* no *DAO* que retorna o `ID` do meu usuário com filtro no `login_name` que é unico. Porém percebi que ficou mais lento que o *Session*, por questões óbvias.

1. Gostaria de saber se isso é a melhor prática? ou
2. se existe outra solução melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar uma base class com os atributos `clientId, createDate, lastDate, isDeleted` para ter o controle de que esta editando ou criando, mas nesse caso sempre vai ser a ultima edicao feita

caso voce queira todos os detalhes do CRUD vc precisa fazer um sistema de log

Comment: Mas como eu iria acessar esses atributos no meu CRUD? Eu instaciaria o base class no controller, passaria os Ids até aí ok. Minha dúvida é como eu acessaria essa informação na classe de CRUD?Entendo que eu não poderia usar static.

Comment: base class nao e para controller e sim para os objetos(entidades) , o db precisa ser modificado para suporta a primeira opcao, caso vc use migration e so implementar o base class e rodar o migration

Comment: e na parte do CRUD voce precisa criar um override ou ate mesmo editar, para salvar lastDate e userId

Comment: caso tenha dificuldade nessa parte, melhor criar o sistema de log, todo vez que o crud e usado vc faz a chamada ao log() para salvar o que foi feito

Comment: Obrigado Hudson.Vou estudar essa implementação.